# Make a multilevel non unique index dataframe unique

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a dataset with some columns that are non unique. I'm trying to find, to no avail, how to make that column an index but, instead of having, for example, 2 rows with the same vale, have that column merged

From this

```
alfa    beta    ganma

 1         4      5
 1         3      17
```

To make alfa an unique index like this

```
        beta     ganma

alfa
 1        4        5
          3        17
```

Is this possible? Because I can't find anywhere how to do it. If so, will it work for multi index level?

Comment: I don't understand how the result you're showing has a "unique" index.

Comment: Unique index in the sense that the index will be the same as if you merge 2 cells in an Excel sheet, so you only have one cell filled, instead of 2 cells each with the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but this just for view purpose and no recommended

```
df.assign(fakekey='').set_index(['alfa','fakekey'])
              beta  ganma
alfa fakekey             
1                4      5
                 3     17
```